# Does Couchbase store JSON as plain text in disk?

Tags: couchbase

I know  that the JSON returned is not the same stored (properties names may not came back in the same order, for example).

But, how does Couchbase stores JSON objects in disk?
Does it takes any advantage of schema or writes it as simple plain text?

In case of huge JSON's, would there be any drawback of compressing it and store as binary? (besides loosing query capacity, and so).

Comment: Here's the wiki page on [Couchbase's file format](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchstore/wiki/Format).  It partially answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the wiki page that Mr Llama linked to, which is great and I am not going to rehash that hear, here are the other answers to your questions.

If you pre-compress the documents in your app, they will of course move over the wire faster and through the queues faster if compressed. The downside is the one you pointed out, you lose any query ability. No indexes, no views, no N1QL. It is just a binary object. If you have a great key pattern your application is using and are going to be going after each object by key and never query then go for it! Couchbase will do great.

All that being said, Couchbase does do snappy compression to files on disk. This obviously saves on disk space, but does not help over the wire or in flight.

Just be aware that Couchbase is working on a new persistence engine called ForestDB that will replace the current Couchstore. https://github.com/couchbase/forestdb

On another note, if you have huge JSONs, it might be worthwhile to look into normalizing them a bit. Obviously that has to make sense with your app, but if you can, then you are only pulling the parts of the information you need, when you need them and you can optimize your use of Couchbase's managed cache. For example, in a user profile store I might need the user's authentication information all of the time and that is in its own tiny document and I want it in the managed cache all the time, but the user's security questions I need rarely and if they are not in the managed cache and Couchbase has to fetch them from disk, big deal. But if they were all in a large user profile document, I would have to fetch the entire object including possibly a lot of data i do not need right this moment. With the proper standardized key patterns, you can get the data you need or use a bulk get and get all of the documents.